# Unable to upload file to specific SharePoint drive,

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph, office365apis

I am trying to upload a file to SharePoint drive using graph API. I am doing OAuth using the below-mentioned link:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&scope=offline_access myfiles.write&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/sharepoint/integrate
```

After the authentication flow, I am getting both access token and refresh token. Using the access token I am able to fetch the drive list by calling the below-mentioned REST API endpoint:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drives

Headers:
Authorization: bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

I am also able to get the list of items present inside a specific drive by calling the below-mentioned REST API endpoint:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drives/{DRIVE_ID}/root/children/

Headers:
Authorization: bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

But when I am trying to upload a file to SharePoint drive using the below-mentioned REST API endpoint:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drives/{DRIVE_ID}/root/{FILE_NAME}:/content

Headers:
Authorization: bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
Content-Length: FILE_SIZE

Data:
File Buffer
```

**I am getting an error from the SharePoint API stating:**

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2021-07-26T12:27:31",
        "request-id": "d54e4e48-738b-4a5c-9499-7e8c6f35ced1",
        "client-request-id": "d54e4e48-738b-4a5c-9499-7e8c6f35ced1"
    }
}
}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here. I am unable to figure it out, been stuck on it for a long time.

My code is in Node.JS, any help related to this would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your endpoint, you miss a colon character after root, and you need to change http method to put to upload files.

```
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drives/{DRIVE_ID}/root:/{FILE_NAME}:/content
```

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http